# Unflattening a simple array with recursive lambda function

Tags: php, recursion

I've been trying to unflatten an array with a recursive lambda function but I can't seem to get my head around it.

```
$test = function( $a, $b ) use ( &$test ) {
    if ( ! count($a) ) return $b;

    $b[array_shift($a)] = []; // Missing logic here.

    return $test( $a, $b );
};

$newArr = $test( [0, 1, 2], []  );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
echo "</pre>";
```

That's the code but I have no idea what to do in the "// Missing logic here." part.

I'd like this recursive lambda function to convert

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Into:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => test
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: You'd have to explain what exactly that "// Missing logic here" should do. There's not an obvious route from `[0, 1, 2]` to `[0 => [1 => [2 => 'test']]]`, when "test" is not specified anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the 2nd argument

```
$test = function( $a) use ( &$test ) {
    // the leaf element
    if ( ! count($a) ) return 'test';
    $c = array_shift($a);
    return [$c => $test($a)];
};

$newArr = $test( [0, 1, 2] );
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/910146)

Comment: I guess `count` and `$c` aren't needed either: `return $a ? [array_shift($a) => $test($a)] : 'test';`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if OP's code is almost working, I usually save as much as possible.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't necessarily suggesting you should change your answer, though. Just commenting.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Well, that's right, especially if take into account that your code is very elegant :)